# EF Core 7 not using my compound keys and throws error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Banging my head on this one. I'm trying to upgrade to Entity Framework Core 7. My class has a `YearTerm` and a `CourseId`. I can't get EF to use my key annotations or fluent API to identify my keys. I've tried the line below as in the Microsoft documents. It's a legacy table so I can't change it.

I've also tried removing the annotation and using Fluent API.

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(YearTerm), nameof(CourseId))]
public class CourseInstance
{
      [Column("YRTR")]
      public string YearTerm { get; set; } 
      [Column("COU_ID")]
      public string CourseId { get; set; }
      .....
 
       [ForeignKey("YearTerm")]
       public YRTRCal YearTearmRecord { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<CourseInstance>()
       .HasKey(c => new { c.YearTerm, c.CourseId });
```

The error I get is :

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'CourseInstanceCourseId'.
> Invalid column name 'CourseInstanceYearTerm'.'

I'm assuming it's not seeing my primary key columns, so it's trying to add them and of course they don't exist either in my table or in my model.

Any ideas?

Thanks;

Tried both the annotations and Fluent API and I expected it to work.

Comment: Do you have those columns in the database (`CourseInstanceCourseId` and `CourseInstanceYearTerm`)?

Comment: The column name in the DB does not match the column name that EF is expecting. You should be able to do something like `.Property(c => c.YearTerm).HasColumnName("YearTerm")` to specify explicit column names, though I'm not sure of the exact syntax for EF7.

Comment: You didn't tell EF that these properties are FK to `Year` and `Course`, respectively (I have to guess these names). What's the rest of the model and mappings concerning these relationships?

Comment: I do not have CourseInstanceCourseId  or CourseInstanceYearTerm in the database.   I believe EF is trying to add them when it can't see primary keys?

Comment: @GertArnold I added the ForeignKey that is on YearTerm in the code but I took that out and tried to run it and I get the same error.

Comment: @DaveCousineau  I did leave the column renames off but I edited the code to include them now.

Comment: That error looks like you may have another entity that references a CourseInstance and needs the FK to CourseInstance mapped because by default EF will expect TableNameColumnName as the FK name(s). So for instance if there is a StudentCourse table that references a CourseInstance containing a CourseId and YearTerm you need to explicitly tell it to use those properties as the FK to CourseInstance or EF will expect the StudentCourse table to have a CourseInstanceCourseId etc. declared.

Comment: @StevePy - Yep that is it.  I created a small class with some of the same data and it worked with the Primary keys.   Wasn't sure with the different annotation if that was it but  when I removed the Foreign Keys on this one it worked.   Thanks!